# Why is wget failing on this Url?

Tags: wget

if I do a wget on BBC RSS it works fine:

```
wget http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml
```

But if I do that with times, I get a 403 forbidden error:

```
wget http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/news/rss
```

Even though this is meant to be the correct rss:
http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/newsrss/?service=rss

What am I missing please?

Comment: Downvoting without comment is useless.  What do you want me to change? I can't see into your head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, supplying wget with a user agent will resolve errors such as 403 forbidden:

```
wget -U "Mozilla" http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/news/rss
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The request may be failing because the Times is filtering based upon the provided user agent.

To change your user agent to impersonate Firefox on OSX, try this:

`wget  --header="Accept: text/html" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0" http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/news/rss`

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.